# jqxgrid combining multiple row selection with checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I am trying to integrate the [jqwidgets jqxgrid jquery plugin](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28arctic%29) so that multiple rows can be selected using the shift/ctrl key on the keyboard as well as using checkboxes.

They have separate options for each in their plugin initialization : "Row Selection" and "CheckBox Selection" but I would like both of these options to work together. How do I achieve this ?

Here are the links to the demos for selection ,
using keyboard (Row selection) : http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/rowselection.htm (selection mode - multiple rows advanced)

using checkboxes (Checkbox selection) : http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/checkboxselection.htm

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to combine these. These're separate Grid selection options which are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

for me works that:
create table with `selectionmode:'checkbox'` and then when the grid is created call `$('#gridId').jqxGrid({selectionmode:'multiplerowsextended'});`